# Binding Textblock with Property having text "Audit" displays text "Audi"

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, textblock

I am binding a TextBLock with a string Property but whenever this Property contains the text "Audit", the actual text displayed on the UI is "Audi". For any other scenario, this works fine.

I am using .Net 4.0 and OS is win XP.

I am not sure if this is a bug but I can't get rid of this. If it is a bug, where do I report WPF bugs? Can anyone else also reproduce this issue? If yes, is there a workaround?

Edit: The Binding for the textblock is:

```
<TextBlock Padding="0,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TaskRoleMapping}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I am sure it's not a problem with the textlength as much bigger text gets displayed alright.

Edit: The TextBlock is contained in a StackPanel

```
<StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">            
        <ContentControl Content="ContentControl" Template="{DynamicResource vector_Summary}" Height="16"/>
        <TextBlock Padding="5,5,0,5" Height="28" 
                   Text="{Binding Path=[LABEL.MAIN.HEADER], Source={x:Static Util:Util.labelDictionary}}" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" 
                   Foreground="#FFFFFF" Margin="1,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto"/>
        <TextBlock Padding="0,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TaskRoleMapping}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>            
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: can u please provide the text of the textblock control.
i just want to see the way u are binding

Comment: Sure the block is wide enough to display the entire text?

Comment: Sure the block is high enough also? (Wrapping) ...and...Padding for TextBlock??

Comment: I have already told that any other text gets displayed correctly big or small, except "Audit". I have checked Padding wrapping and everything else. Could anyone reproduce it?

Comment: Voting to close. You haven't hinted at trying *any* of the obvious things, nor have you provided enough code to reproduce the problem. Have you checked the text in Snoop? Have you hard-coded the text to "Audit"? Have you changed the font/font size? Have you simplified to the point where you can provide a repro?

Comment: Thanks for the help Kent, I tried and it worked. I had no idea as to changing the font is any solution. I had tried with bigger text, hardcoded the text, and made sure that the Property containing the text was present with the correct text in the DataContext. I am still wondering as to why it was a problem with the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like  Kent Boogaart's comment/points. Basically 't' char is being cut off/out from the view. So change the font size to smaller, or remove "Bold" or introduce min size  of the TextBlock, or it's parent and 't' in "Audi" will magically appear

Comment: Well. yeah, it did. But I just changed the font style from **Segoe UI** to **Arial**. I am still not able to figure out as to how even bigger text than "Audit" was displayed properly. And why changing the font style can make it work. Just for information, I tried to use the same textblock outside the Stackpanel and it works. I have a Stackpanel which contains a ContentPresenter and two TextBlocks. I have edited the question with the code for the same. Is there any explanation for the same?

Comment: I think another key to your puzzle might be the use of a StackPanel what happens if you change that to a grid?